# How to stop Django to create lot of unnecessary tables

Tags: python, django

I have two databases defined in my `setting.py` file.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME': 'monitoring',
            'USER': 'root',
            'PASSWORD': '',
            'HOST': 'localhost',
            'PORT': '',
    },
    'source' :{
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME': 'source_db',
            'USER': '*****',
            'PASSWORD': '*****',
            'HOST': '*****',
            'PORT': '****',
    }
}
```

I need to access some tables in source_db which django is not allowing to do so unless I migrate the db. So, once we run command `python manage.py migrate --database=source` , Django is creating some tables in server db. Since we are not allowed to create tables in server db, is there any way to stop django doing so, **or any way to access tables without migrating the db?**

This is the list of tables which we don't want to create.

```
+--------------------------------+
| Tables_in_source_db            |
+--------------------------------+
| auth_group                     |
| auth_group_permissions         |
| auth_permission                |
| auth_user                      |
| auth_user_groups               |
| auth_user_user_permissions     |
| dashboard_monitoring_features  |
| dashboard_monitoring_modelinfo |
| dashboard_monitoring_product   |
| django_admin_log               |
| django_content_type            |
| django_migrations              |
| django_session                 |
+--------------------------------+
```

Comment: if you dont want to create tables, dont run migrate command

Comment: @Exprator, I need to access some tables in source_db, which django is not allowing unless I migrate the db.

Comment: I find it strange that you would be allowed to modify the "source" db schema but not to create new tables - I don't really get the point (from a dba POV) but well, I'm n dba either. Anyway: there's a documentation on database routing, which may (or not) answer your question: https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.0/topics/db/multi-db/#allow_migrate

Comment: Have you tried faking migrations on database Source? `python manage.py migrate --fake --database=source` might help.

Comment: @VishalMopari though --fake is not creating lot of tables, still it is creating one django_migrations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to migrate / create tables in the `default` database and not `source` database, then you have to define app and database when you run migrations. Like:

```
python manage.py migrate dashboard --database=default
```

This will run migration in the `dashboard` app and create tables in the `default` database.

Next thing you want to do is set your `source` models to [non-managed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#managed). You do by specifying `managed = False` in the meta class of the model:

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    ... your fields here ...
    class Meta:
        managed = False
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#managed):

> If False, no database table creation or deletion operations will be
>   performed for this model. This is useful if the model represents an
>   existing table or a database view that has been created by some other
>   means.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want particular tables, then remove

```
'django.contrib.auth`,
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.admin',
```

and `dashboard` app

from your `INSTALLED_APPS`

Comment: No, we have to create tables for default db but not for source_db.

Answer (score 0):

Probably nobody was clear about what the author of the question was trying to do. So let me start with the context.

### Context

By default, Django uses a database named `default`. Let's say I have a `CustomModel` in a `CustomApp` for which the table should be created in a new database called `source_db`.
Thus we have two databases: 1)`default` and 2)`source_db`.
We want the default tables like `auth_group` required by apps like `django.contrib.auth` to be created only in `default`. The `source_db` should have and only have tables from `CustomApp`. How do we do this?

### Solution 1: I recommend this method

First, refer to [Multiple Databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/multi-db/), the official documentation to understand the routing basics. Give special attention to `allow_migrate()`. Let me insist, understanding of this documentation is at most important to understand the rest of this solution.

Let's begin:

1. In your `CustomModel`, set `managed = True` in the meta data:

   ```
   class CustomModel(models.Model):
       # your fields here ...

       class Meta:
           managed = True
   ```

   This specifies that the table creation and alteration for this model should be taken care of by Django.
2. Write your `CustomDBRouter` for tables in `CustomApp`. (Refer to [Multiple Databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/multi-db/) for this). Don't forget to define `allow_migrate()`.

   ```
   def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
       """
       Make sure the 'CustomApp' only appear in the 'source_db' database.
       """
       if app_label == 'CustomApp':
           # if app=CustomApp and db=source_db, migrate
           return db == 'source_db'
       return None # No suggestions, ask the next router in the list
   ```
3. Go to your `settings.py` and split the list `INSTALLED_APPS` as follows:

   ```
   MY_APPS = [                       # List of apps defined by you
       'customApp'
   ]
   INSTALLED_APPS = [                # Full list of apps
       'django.contrib.admin',
       'django.contrib.auth',
       'django.contrib.contenttypes',
       'django.contrib.sessions',
       'django.contrib.messages',
       'django.contrib.staticfiles'
   ] + MY_APPS
   ```
4. Now add a new router to project-app(default-app) folder (The folder where you have your `settings.py`)
   This router should look like:

   ```
   from project.settings import MY_APPS

   class DefaultDBRouter(object):        
       def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
           """
           If an app is not defined by me, migrate only if database is 'default'
           """
           if app_label not in MY_APPS:
               return db == 'default'
           return False
   ```
5. Now when adding `DefaultDBRouter` to `DATABASE_ROUTERS` in `settings.py`, make sure that this is the last router in the list. This is at most important since the routers are processed in the order listed.

   ```
   DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['customApp.dbRouter.CustomDBRouter', 'project.dbRouter.DefaultDBRouter']
   ```
6. Finally, you can migrate using the following commands:

   ```
   python manage.py makemigrations               # Make migrations for all apps
   python manage.py migrate                      # Do migrations to 'default'
   python manage.py migrate --database=source_db # Do migrations to 'source'
   ```

#### Solution 2: I don't recommend this

1. Follow step 1 and 2 of Solution 1.
2. Now, while doing migrations follow these steps:

   ```
   python manage.py makemigrations  # Make migrations for all apps
   python manage.py migrate         # Do migrations to `default`
   python manage.py migrate customApp --database=source_db 
   # Do migrations to 'source_db' from `customApp` only
   ```

Since tables like `auth_group` do not belong to migrations of `customApp`, they won't be created in the last command. You can add these 3 commands to a shell script to make your job easy. Note that, as the number of apps and databases increase, this method will look dirty. On the other hand, Solution-1 provides a clean way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for another issue but stumbled upon this question. The answer is to use a database router. In the project's `root_app` create a file (I called mine `model.py`) and add the following settings:

```py
from <app> import models as app_models

class DatabaseRouter(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """ Route for when Django is reading the model(s). """

        if model in (
            app_models.<name>,
        ):
            return "project_db"

        return "default"

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """ Route for when Django is writing the model(s). """

        if model in (
            app_models.<name>
        ):
            return "project_db"

        return "default"
```

Then inside your `settings.py` you should have:

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {"ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3", "NAME": ":memory:"},
    "project_db": { ... },
}
```

And the following line:

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ("root_app.models.DatabaseRouter",)
```

You should be able to generalize the above for your liking.